# How to communicate over HTTPS using VFP

Tags: xml, web-services, https, visual-foxpro

Background: I was asked to create a 'middle man' web service for a program written in Visual Fox Pro(VFP) as VFP is not able to communicate over HTTPS, only HTTP. This VFP program must communicate with a different web service, so my web service must just edit the XML file to be HTTPS 'compliant'.

I have never worked with web services before this, but have written a few basic web services to learn about them.
I now need to understand what I have to do to the regular XML file to make it 'compliant' with HTTPS and not just HTTP.
I apologise if my jargon is off as I am still finding my way around web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VFP can send HTTPS requests using [West Wind Internet & Client Tools
for Visual FoxPro](http://www.west-wind.com/WestwindClientTools.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Https or Http, communicating to a web service from VFP is not a trivial task. What I personally do is to create "a middle man" activex using C#. I can "talk" back and forth to web service from C# easily and provide a few public methods that accept and return XML that VFP can use (so from VFP's standpoint it become a simple XML string for passing parameters or getting results back).

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, but was more interested to know if there was a better way, I was not completely excited about paying for software to do this, as it was only the once I'd ever need it.

Comment: It doesn't need a payment for the software. Visual Studio Community editions are given for free by MS to individuals, or to companies with up to 5 developers. There is also the express versions, and also building this kind of takes less time than trying to do it in VFP.

Comment: The payment I was referring to was for the other answer